# JavaScript object cloning

Tags: javascript, object, cloning

Can anyone explain why the `obj` returns `{a:2}` instead of `{a:1}` in this case?

```
var obj = {a:1};
var data = {b:obj};
data.b.a = 2;

console.log(obj); // {a:2}
```

Comment: You did change the property?

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: As in most languages, objects are references in JavaScript... (And this doesn't have anything to do with shallow copying, by the way.)

Comment: @minitech If objects are references, names are people. References refer to objects, and objects contain more references, but they're quite separate.

Comment: Can you explain why you expect it to work differently?

Comment: @delnan: Oops, that was just a bad accidental word. (Too late to change it now.) Thanks though.

Comment: @GGG because I created an object with another object inside. And then I edit "data" object but not "obj". I thought it will work like it does with variables

Comment: But you didn't create another object, you just created another reference to the same object. If you want to "clone" objects without copying properties, try using the prototype chain.

Comment: @GGG I need to make full independent copy of the object inside another object, to be able to change it with no conflicts.

Comment: @artnikpro try something like this: `function F(){}; F.prototype = obj; var clonedObj = new F();`

Comment: @GGG thank you! Seems like it works!

Comment: no problem, see also [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3):

objects in javascript are by reference, so when you change one reference you changed them.  The meaning of this is you just created a shallow copy, you need to do a deep clone.

Deep copy can be made with jQuery this way:

```
// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
```

Read this why I used jQuery:
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/601179)

<sub>(It's John Resig here on Stackoverflow...)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you tell me please how can I copy the `obj` with no conflicts without jquery or other libraries plz?

Comment: @artnikpro, it can be done with this: `newObj = JSON.decode(JSON.encode(oldObj));`, about performance and other problems... read the linked answer.

Comment: @artnikpro: Follow the link in the second comment to your question.

Comment: Seems like it is not simple to do. I will try to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're not cloning objects but rather setting additional references to the same variable.  data.obj.a and obj.a point to the exact same memory location.  Line 3 sets this memory value to 2.

To do a deep clone, try this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

if using an NS derived browser like FF:

```
var data = { b: eval ( obj . toSource ( ) ) } ;
```

or

```
var data = { b: eval ( uneval ( obj ) ) } ;
```

if not:

```
Object . function . deepClone = function(){ 
/*
     highly non-trivial to accommodate objects like:
              animal=123; animal.beastly=432;                                        ie. object "overloading"
              monster = new ( function ( ) { this . this = this } ) ( )            ie. self-referential / recursive
      Note: JSON cannot do these  but  toSource () can handle recursive structures
      alert ( new ( function ( ) { this . this = this } ) ( )  . toSource ( )  );
                                                                                                                   ie.    #1={this:#1#}
      alert ( new ( function ( ) { this [ this ] = this } ) ( )  . toSource ( )  );
                                                                                                                   ie.     #1={'[object Object]':#1#}
      alert ( new ( function ( ) { this [ this . toSource ( )  ] = this } ) ( )  . toSource ( )  );
                                                                                                                   ie.     #1={'({})':#1#}
      alert (    (     #1 = { '({})' : #1# }      )   . toSource ( )  );
                                                                                                                   ie.     #1={'({})':#1#}
*/
 }

var data = { b: obj . deepClone ( )  } ;
```

There are  many, many, many **attempts** posted in SO to do deepClone as well as
[The structured clone algorithm - Web developer guide | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm#Another_way.3A_deep_copy.E2.80.8E)

hint: The Emperor has No Clothes