# JavaScript object pushed into an array

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360)

I have this code:

```
var temp = [];
var obj = {name:"1"};
temp.push(obj);
obj.name = "2";
temp.push(obj);
```

What I'm expecting to be true:

```
temp[0].name == "1" && temp[1].name == "2";
```

What actually happens:

```
temp[0].name == "2" && temp[1].name == "2";
```

Why does this happen, and how I can get what I'm expecting?

Comment: ... which is the solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417645/javascript-object-cloning/14417676#14417676

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript arrays hold references to objects, rather than objects themselves. When you push an object into the array it does not create a new object, but it simply puts a reference to the object, that `obj` also points to, into the array.

So in the end obj, temp[0], and temp[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) all point to the same object. To actually create a completely new object, you can use [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) or jQuery.extend({},obj). Though in your case it's easy enough just to create a new simple object using `var newobj = {name="2"}`

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript objects are passed by reference. In your case you have only one object "obj", and temp[0] and temp[1] are pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

`obj` being an object is added by reference in the array so your actually adding the same `obj` twice.